# Code to generate a link that adds an event to a Google Calendar

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api

I have set up code on our Wordpress site that dynamically generates a link that allows people to add our events to their Google Calendar.  This code pulls fields for date/time, event title, and event address built within the Toolset plugin to get added to the URL as needed in the format needed.

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;"><a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&dates=[types field='start-date-and-time' style='text' format='Ymd'][/types]T[types field='start-date-and-time' style='text' format='His'][/types][types field='end-date-and-time' style='text' format='Ymd'][/types]T[types field='end-date-and-time' style='text' format='His'][/types]&text=[wpv-post-title]&location=[types field='ride-start-address'][/types]&trp=false&ctz=America/New_York&sprop=website:https://floridafreewheelers.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">+ Google Calendar</a></div>
```

This code produces a link URL like this example:

https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20231022T080000T&text=October%20Picnic%20Ride&location=1104%20Lakeshore%20Blvd,%20St%20Cloud,%20FL%2034769&trp=false&ctz=America/New_York&sprop=website:https://floridafreewheelers.com

Everything about this looks correct to me.  The date and time for this *should* be

October 22, 2023 at 8:00am

But when I go to the Google page this link leads to, the date/time there shows as

Oct 15, 2023
10:00pm
to
11:00pm

Actually, clicking on the link above now after making this post, I see the date/time is now showing as

Oct 17, 2023
8:00am
to
9:00am
Oct 17, 2023

I have also filed a support ticket with Toolset support to ask about this, but I believe everything is working as it should from their end because the URL looks correct to me.

Does anyone here have any idea why the date/time would show incorrectly on the Google side here?

Comment: Toolset support provided the solution to this one.   They found that I have to add a / between the start date/time and the end date/time.